# Error in Taylor series using Mathematica

Tags: complex-analysis, mathematica

How many terms should be used in taylor series expansion of the function f(z) = e^z around z = 0 for a specific value of z = 30 + 30 i to get an error of less than 0.05 using Mathematica?

```
Poly[x_ , n_] := Series[Exp[x] , {x,0,n}]
errorTaylor[x_ , n_] := (1/Factorial[n])*Integrate[((x-t)^n)*Exp[t],{t,0,x}]
Reduce[{errorTaylor[30+30 I,n]<0.05},n,Complexes]
```

The output was

°°° **Reduce** Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Reduce require exact input, providing Reduce with an exact version of the system may help.

```
Reduce[{e^(30+30 I)(Gamma[1+n]-Gamma[1+n,30+30 I])/(n!)<0.05 if Re[n]>-1},n, **C**]
```

Comment: Great.  Reduce won't do it for you.  That means: You have to think!  I guess you do not evaluate the integral for the error in closed form; instead you should get a good upper estimate for it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how do I get an upper estimate for the integral?